# Jquery Event in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a script to select form options. How can I change the document ready function to Javascript instead of using jQuery?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function FormFill() {
            if {
                var el1 = document.getElementsByName("FormOption1")[0];
            if(typeof el1 !== 'undefined') {el1 = 1;}         
                var el2 = document.getElementsByName("FormOption2")[0];
            if(typeof el2 !== 'undefined') {el2 = 2;}  
            }, 100);
        }
    }
setTimeout(FormFill,5000);
});
```

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` is the JS equivalent to `$(document).ready`. Is that what you need?

Comment: Check for extended answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery

Comment: FYI `document.getElementsByName("FormOption1")[0]` is wasteful as it scans the entire DOM, when you are only interested in the first one found. Also, it returns a "live" node list. Use `document.querySelector("form[name='FormOption1']")` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use DOMContentLoaded. Here is the full example.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    function FormFill() {
            if {
                var el1 = document.getElementsByName("FormOption1")[0];
            if(typeof el1 !== 'undefined') {el1 = 1;}         
                var el2 = document.getElementsByName("FormOption2")[0];
            if(typeof el2 !== 'undefined') {el2 = 2;}  
            }, 100);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(FormFill,5000);
});
```

Comment: Seems to be a few errors now. [1]  just on the first variable 'Expected an identifier and instead saw var' [2] on the closing braces 'Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression'